# Execution flow altered and exception thrown after Hg merge

Tags: c#, mercurial, visual-studio-2013

I'm getting a strange exception from some code in my MCF server app that has been working for months. I am using the Mindscape Lightspeed 5 ORM, VS2013 / C# and SQL Server 2008R2.

Here's the code where the exception is thrown:

```
internal byte EplantId
{
    get
    {
        if (_eplantId == 0)
        {
            if (UnitOfWork.Factories.Count(f => f.IsDefault) != 1)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(
                    "Unable to determine default ePlant. Contact Engineering.");
            }

            var eplant = UnitOfWork.Factories.FirstOrDefault(f => f.IsDefault);
            if (eplant == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(
                    "Unable to determine default ePlant. Contact Engineering.");
            }

            _eplantId = eplant.EplantId;
        }

        return _eplantId;
    }
}
```

When I step through this piece of code in debug mode I see the current line of execution start at the top and move through in a predictable manner - if (_eplantId == 0), then if (UnitOfWork...Count()) -- then it jumps back up to if (eplantId == 0), back to if (UnitOfWork...), then throws the exception.

This started after a particularly hairy merge (TortoiseHg) that required a bit of manual intervention. However, the merge was in a separate module from this one. Same project, different file.

I moved some code around in an unrelated module and the behavior changed. Now it steps past the the first .Count statement and lands on the .FirstOrDefault statement, then back to the top and repeats the sequence before throwing the exception.

I am completely stumped by this one. I don't even know how to go about finding what or where the problem might be. Do you have any ideas, tips or suggestions for me? What might cause this exception to be thrown? The exception is thrown from the Mindscape library and I have no source code access to that.  I am 100% certain the library is not at fault though, as it has been working perfectly for months, as I said, and it still works perfectly in my default branch.

I have forcibly cleaned all binary files from the project with no change in behavior. I have tried moving the second bit of the logic inside an else statement with no effect.  Has anyone run into this before and successfully worked their way out of it?

Comment: Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!

Answer (score 0):

The answer here is plainly obvious now in hindsight.  Essentially, who gives a fig what is making the code act funny, the error was introduced via a botched merge.

The solution is to back out the merge and try again until it works.  In my case I had to manually rebuild one source file that had been extensively modified on both branches by different projects / people.  Once I did that everything worked as expected.